# I want to give the thumb image to NSSlider in swift

Tags: swift, macos, nsstoryboard

I`m working on an editor app, where I need to add image in the slider thumb as I'm doing macOS development so unfortunately I'm not able to do that in macOS, there is available in UISlider.

[image]

this is what I have and I want to insert the thumb Image as give below

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74067905/13044198 check this..

Comment: @Vishnu I have attached the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I find out the solution, I hope this will help you all.

I made a NSSliderCell class and override the function drawKnob.

```
class CustomSliderCell: NSSliderCell {

@IBInspectable var knobImage: NSImage?{
    didSet{
        if let knobImage = knobImage{
            self.knobImage = knobImage
        }
        
    }}

override func drawKnob(_ knobRect: NSRect) {
    
        var rect = knobRect
        
        rect.size = NSSize(width: rect.width, height: rect.height - 4)
        self.knobImage?.draw(in: rect)
    
        
}
```

}

just assign this class to you nsslider cell from your storyboard and change the image on your storyboard.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtfWH.png)

The Result is given Below :
[This is the resultant Image][2]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtfWH.png)